# Cache-busting for html

Tags: angularjs, html, caching, cache-control

Ive read about this method called cache-busting that allows us to add version parameters to our js and css files so that clients wont have to clear cache every time we have an update. However, I didn`t read any about html.

Is there any method that allows us to load latest html file changes without clearing the cache?

P.S. I dont know about others but I just discovered that it is angularjs that is caching my templates. I posted my own solution anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it.
Just append a parameter string to your routes that are referencing your html files just like what we did on cache-busting for css and js.

```
.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: "../views/login.html?v=" + versionNumber,
        controller: "LoginController"
    })
```

Where 'versionNumber' is a global variable.

Comment: I recommend setting a second variable such as _versionUrl = "?v=" + versionNumber_ so that you don't have to put "?v=" at the end of every templateUrl in your app.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The link in the original answer is broken.

Aside from the accepted answer, the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816258/how-to-reload-templates-html-when-releasing-a-new-version-of-a-spa) offer interesting alternatives depending upon your build process.

**ORIGINAL**

You should be able to force reload the browser via js, while applying a hash to the url, via page-specific javascript that exists only on an updated version of the html file.

This would allow you to know when you are receiving the latest version of the file.

https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/static-file-cache-busting

Comment: @michaelmsm89 Thank you. Updated answer.